# Samsung screen zoom ruining my cordova built android app

Tags: cordova, samsung-mobile

I am making an app with Cordova. The app is not responsive on all devices. I had a problem with increasing the device font size, ruining the app, which I have overwritten in the mainactivity.java.

But I also have a problem with Samsung settings of screen zoom. Using screen zoom ruins the display of my app. I have noticed games made in Unity overwrite this setting somehow. Does anyone know how to overwrite the Samsung screen zoom settings?

I want to overwrite the samsung screen zoom settings without causing my app design to change into a mess.